# Не работает JS код

Tags: javascript

Не работает JS код как в отдельном файле `.js` формата, так и сверху `body`.
Если вставляю его в самом низу `body`, то все работает отлично.
Подскажите как решить проблему перенеся в отдельный файл?
Почему то `<script type="text/javascript" scr="javascript.js"></script>` не работает.
Может что не то сделал :(

Сам код:

```js
var menuElem = document.body.querySelectorAll('div.menu, div.top_content, div.menu_nav > ul, div.menu_search > a > i.first_search, div.icon_search, div.social, div.content');
    var sidebarElem = document.body.querySelector('.open');
    sidebarElem.onclick = function() {
      for (var i = 0; i < menuElem.length; i++) {
        menuElem[i].classList.toggle('close');
      };
    };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Код не работает, потому что в момент его выполнения еще нет нужных элементов.

В качестве решения:

1. подключать файл .js в конце body
2. выполнять данный код когда все уже будет доступно, например по событию [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded)
3. использовать [атрибут defer](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer) на загружаемом скрипте

Comment: Спасибо, воспользовался 3 вариантом, только вместо defer решил поставить async

Comment: @Владислав, вообще async делает не то, что тебе нужно, и если у тебя заработало - значит просто повезло :)

Comment: Я прочитал что при атрибуте async загрузка при возможности идет асинхронно, так как код маленький не думаю что для современной скорости интернета это проблема) Или может быть я в чем то ошибаюсь?

Comment: @Владислав, я и говорю, повезло в данном конкретном случае. Если что-то поменяется, то никто не гарантирует, что ничего не сломается

Comment: @Владислав атрибут `async` не ждет окончания загрузки документа, в отличии от `defer`.